# Что за слайдер?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.
Кто-то знает что за слайдер изображений [**тут**](http://www.lookatme.ru/flow/posts/design-radar/154119-eksperimentalnaya-shkola-v-stokgolme) стоит?
p.s. на картинке с деревом.

Очень уж приглянулся мне :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам название? Скачайте с того же сайта и пользуйтесь )

Comment: та видимо придется)  
хотел чтоб с мануалом было =))

Comment: Да там вроде все просто )

Comment: Еще я думаю что это модификация этой галереи: http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/ http://www.phunulamdep.com/ - тут её пример. Анимация основана на смене opacity

Comment: Кстати на будущее, вы и сами смогли бы найти её, если бы в гугл куски кода пробовали вставлять. Я именно так ищу неизвестные скрипты. 
Желательно имена переменных где подлиннее. Вообщем способ необычный но работает )

Answer (score 0):

[Animated JavaScript Slideshow](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/) - не?

Comment: та вроде нет  
тот затемняем между переходами